# Storing an Array of Ints to NSUserDefaults results in 0 upon retrieving

Tags: arrays, swift, int, nsuserdefaults

I have a need to store a `UIColor` in `NSUserDefaults`, and I found a recommendation to use an `Array` to store the color values for red, green, and blue. I have implemented this and it was previously working in Xcode 6 beta 4, but now that I try it in beta 5, the values retrieved from the `Array` are all 0 (therefore the color is always black). I confirmed the `Array` created and stored into `NSUserDefaults` did contain the proper values (any `Int` between 0 and 255). I can't figure out what the issue is here.

```
//Store in user defaults
var red: CGFloat = 0.0, green: CGFloat = 0.0, blue: CGFloat = 0.0
selectColor?.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: nil) //selectedColor is an optional UIColor
let redInt = Int(red * 255.0), greenInt = Int(green * 255.0), blueInt = Int(blue * 255.0)
let colorArray = [redInt, greenInt, blueInt] 
//debugger shows: colorArray = ([Int]) 3 values: 255, 192, 3
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(colorArray, forKey: "textColor")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

//Retrieve from user defaults later
let colorArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("textColor")
//debugger shows: colorArray = [AnyObject]! Some
println(colorArray[0]) //prints 0
println(colorArray[1]) //prints 0
println(colorArray[2]) //prints 0
```

I have tried explicitly setting the colorArray to an `[Int]` when I fetch it  but the result is the same - prints 0. In that case the debugger shows `colorArray = ([Int]) 3 values: 0, 0, 0` instead of `[AnyObject]! Some`. Is this a bug I should report to Apple, or is there a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could circumvent the whole aggravation by simply storing the color as a string.

Look at one of the many color utilities that allow you to convert `UIColor` into a hex or other string very conveniently. A good one is e.g. https://github.com/Namvt/MVColor.

Comment: I decided to store them as a `String` with the values separated by commas, then convert it to an `Array` via `componentsSeparatedByString`, afterwards converting each index to an `Int` and then to `CGFloat` to work with the `UIColor` API. A pain, but it's working great again.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject([1,2,3], forKey: "test")
let x = defaults.objectForKey("test") as [Int]   
// [1,2,3]
```

Interestingly, when I don't do the cast the result is

```
let x = defaults.objectForKey("test")    
// [__NSCFNumber, __NSCFNumber, __NSCFNumber]
```

This clearly means that swift has no way of knowing what kind of array will be returned, so the cast seems to take care of that ambiguity.

NB: `arrayForKey()` works just the same.

Comment: When fetching with `as [Int]` appended to the end, both with `objectForKey` and `arrayForKey`, it still shows and prints 0 for the three indexes, even when I don't set the object to my generated colorArray and instead use `[1,2,3]` like you've done.

Comment: Hmm I'm noticing some very odd behavior. When I reset the simulator, it prints 255,255,255 because that's my default registered values. If I change it to any other color it remains 255,255,255. But if I change it to black, it will print 0,0,0, but then I cannot change it back to any other color after that not even back to white. Very odd.

Comment: Looks like the error is elsewhere. Try to simplify to eliminate any additional problems. I will post an alternative answer for you.